# flex effect on visible event

Tags: apache-flex, effects

I would like to create a component that apply a resize effect when the it is visible:

I did this:

```
<s:Panel id="loginPanel" title="Connect" creationCompleteEffect="customResize" 
                             showEffect="customResize" hideEffect="fadeOut"
                             width="400" height="300" includeIn="login">
```

with:

```
    <fx:Declarations>
            <!--  Effects declaration  -->
            <s:Fade id="fadeIn" alphaFrom="0.0" alphaTo="1.0" duration="500"/>
            <s:Fade id="fadeOut" alphaFrom="1.0" alphaTo="0.0" duration="500"/>
            <s:Animate id="customResize" duration="1000">
                <s:SimpleMotionPath property="percentWidth" valueFrom="0" valueTo="100"/>
                <s:SimpleMotionPath property="percentHeight" valueFrom="0" valueTo="100"/>
            </s:Animate>
        </fx:Declarations>
```

The problem is that when the component is displayed for the first time, the effect is correctly played but when the state change for example from "login" to "working" then back to "login", the effect isn't played anymore.

I thought that a visibility event would have been dispatched and the showEffect applied but it seems that the state changes don't work like I was expecting.

How can I apply the effect each time the component is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure the states are toggling the visible property? 
Try to force Visible property to change:

```
<s:Fade id="fadeIn" alphaFrom="0.0" alphaTo="1.0" duration="500" effectStart="loginPanel.visible = true"/>

<s:Fade id="fadeOut" alphaFrom="1.0" alphaTo="0.0" duration="500" effectEnd="loginPanel.visible = false"/>
```

Comment: a good example: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/20/triggering-effects-when-a-containers-visibility-is-changed/